# Woocommerce Default Product Page - Sort / Order by Category

Tags: wordpress, sorting, woocommerce, categories

Ok, So I got a woocommerce shop with different categories, lets say these are: shirts, pants and shoes.

Now I got a different page for each category, but I also have the Main Product Page where all of the products are shown. I can change the order the items to things like lets say: Popularity or Price.

But the problem is, I want to sort products to be of the same category below eachother on the Main Product Page. So like when you go to the Main Product Page where all the products are, they are shown in this way when you scroll down: first all shirts, then all pants, then all shoes.

I cant find any options or any solutions on the internet... how can I do this? To me it sounds like common sense to have to want products sorted in that way, yet I cant find a way to do it.

Anything would help, like: a plugin, custom css or php file changes..

O yeah before I get to mention, the order by category must also be the main sorting / order.

Hope someone can help :O :O

Comment: This is not a build in feature of WooCommerce you can adjust in the woocommerce admin dashboard. The theme you are using has to offer this functionality. So if in your theme settings there is nothing like sorting options, then you have to edit the woocommerce/archive-product.php in your theme or filter the looping functions of woocommerce. In each case you would have to do some coding. Or you install / buy a theme that offer this kind of sorting.

Comment: you could add a new custom sort option with code and if your theme allows this in the settings, set this as main sorting.

There are enough examples online of how you can do this, but you will have to determine the category-based query in code. Do you have an idea? what that query would look like? have you already tried this via SQL in your database?

Comment: I'm not that advanced, I know the basics of CSS and know where to put codes a little bit, but I cant write code. I really hope someone can help me with this, since what i mentioned seems like a basic (and logical) option to me. The theme I use is Betheme